# Errors in Add Image Popup, Media Library Tab: "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in wp-includes/query.php"

Tags: errors, media-library

I am getting errors like

```
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /data/www/ae/wp-includes/query.php on line 2390
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /data/www/ae/wp-includes/query.php on line 2399
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /data/www/ae/wp-includes/query.php on line 2399
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /data/www/ae/wp-includes/query.php on line 2399
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /data/www/ae/wp-includes/query.php on line 2399
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /data/www/ae/wp-includes/query.php on line 2399
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /data/www/ae/wp-includes/query.php on line 2399
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /data/www/ae/wp-includes/query.php on line 2399
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /data/www/ae/wp-includes/query.php on line 2399
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Have your tried disabling all plugins and switching to default theme? Do the errors still appear? If you do that we can narrow down what is causing the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the hotfix plugin may help to solve the problem. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hotfix/

Currently I am using wordpress3.1.3 and got same type errors while browsing the media(media list page) in admin panel and hotfix plugin solves that.

Answer (score 2):

You're not alone. It's a problem with a variable type assumption in `WP_Query`. I fixed it by editing line `2390` in `wp-includes/query.php` from this;

```
$q_status = explode(',', $q['post_status']);
```

To this:

```
$q_status = is_array( $q['post_status'] ) ? $q['post_status'] : explode(',', $q['post_status']);
```

I was going to submit to trac, but I've just checked the trunk and it looks like it's already been fixed. Hopefully it'll make the next release :)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem after upgrading to 3.1.3, too. The manual fix you described didn't work for me. I might have overlooked something but couldn't find it if I did.

As suggested by some other users, I installed the Wordpress Hotfix plugin and it corrected the problem...

Michael

Answer (score 0):

First of all open query.php file into wp-includes folder. find this code..

if ( isset($q['post_status']) && $q['post_status'] != '' ) {
            $statuswheres = array();
            $q_status = explode(',', $q['post_status']);

and Replace with :--

if ( ! empty( $q['post_status'] ) ) {
            $statuswheres = array();
            $q_status = $q['post_status'];
            if ( ! is_array( $q_status ) )
                $q_status = explode(',', $q_status);

Answer (score 0):

install http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hotfix/ and it'll fix it.